# Bootstrap button, how to click multiple times

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, button, rows

I have a counter which adds number of rows to a table based on what the counter is. I have one button that increase the counter every time its clicked, but it only works one time.

php:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['Addmore'])) {      
    $NoOfUsers++;

<form action="addstudent.php">
<th>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm spoiler-trigger pull-right" aria-label="Left Align" name="Addmore" title="Add Row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
    </button>
</th>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide you code details

Comment: You have a variable that is not stored in a session or anywhere else,every time the code executes it is reset.

Answer (score 0):

**php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST['Addmore'])) {
?><button class="btn btn-default"><?php
echo $_SESSION['NoOfUsers'] ? ++$_SESSION['NoOfUsers'] : $_SESSION['NoOfUsers']=1;
?></button><?php
}
```

or **JavaScript**

```
<button id="counter" class="btn btn-default">0</button>
<script>
    $('#counter').on('click',function(){$( this ).html(1 * $( this ).html() + 1)});    
</script>
```